# Spring Security and Angular js basic authentication not working

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

I am trying to build a simple application in angular-js and spring security.I am using basic authentication.Whenever browsing home page ,i am getting basic authentication pop-up for user name password.If i cancel it and login with correct password,application is working fine.But if i enter wrong password the same basic authentication pop -up is coming.I am sending X-Requested-With header in every request and it is visible in header fiends also.Any one has any idea,what's going wrong here?

Angular :

```
'use strict';

var todoApp=angular.module('todoApp',['ngRoute']);

todoApp.config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider',function($routeProvider,$httpProvider){

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl:'resources/templates/Home.html',
        controller:'HomeController'
    }).otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});



}]);


'user strict';
todoApp.controller('NavBarController',function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location, $route){


    $scope.credentials = {};

    $scope.login = function() {

        authenticate($scope.credentials, function(authenticated) {
            if (authenticated) {
                console.log("Login succeeded")
                $location.path("/");
                $scope.error = false;
                $rootScope.authenticated = true;
            } else {
                console.log("Login failed")
                $location.path("/");
                $scope.error = true;
                $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            }
        })
    };

    $scope.logout=function(){
        $http.post('logout', {}).success(function() {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $location.path("/");
        }).error(function(data) {
            console.log("Logout failed")
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        });

    }



    var authenticate=function(credentials,callback){

        //create headers for request
        var headers= credentials? {
            authorization:"Basic "
                    +btoa(credentials.username+":"+credentials.password)}:{};


        //request to http basic service

        $http.get('user/authenticate',{
            headers:headers
        }).success(function(data){
            if(data.name){
                $rootScope.authenticated=true
            }else{
                $rootScope.authenticated=false;

            }
            callback && callback($rootScope.authenticated);
        }).error(function(data){
                $rootScope.authenticated=false;
                callback && callback(false);
        });

    };

    authenticate();

});




security configuration:

<sec:http  use-expressions="true">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/Home.html" access="permitAll"/>
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <sec:http-basic/>
    </sec:http>


    <sec:authentication-manager>
            <sec:authentication-provider>
                <sec:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" id="userDetailsService"/>
    </sec:authentication-provider>

    </sec:authentication-manager>




Headers:

Content-Language:en
Content-Length:1160
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 12 Jun 2015 02:46:18 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Spring Security Application"
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=A06CEC616C9A34B915EA298A890C5E80
Host:localhost:9999
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:9999/todoapp/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.124 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending `WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Spring Security Application"` will cause the browser to show a login form.

You need to serve your initial angular assets without requiring Basic authentication.